# How do I access the contents of a std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, netbeans, shared-ptr

Here is my code.

```
std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent> WSUStudent::registerStudent(
   std::string lastName,
   std::string firstName
)
{
   auto result = std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent>(new WSUStudent(lastName, firstName));

   s_allStudents.insert(&result);

   return result;
}
```

I have successfully managed to change the function so it returns a shared_ptr instead of a normal pointer. I have successfully encapsulated the 'new' statement with a shared pointer, as per the assignment (I think), but the line of code below 'auto' didn't work without the &, and it doesn't work WITH the &. I receive an error stating that there is no matching function call, with or without the &. That line of code is attempting to insert the new student (or a pointer to the new student?) into the list of all students. However the 'insert' method is not locally overridden, so I'm not quite sure what to do here. Error printed below.

```
/mnt/hgfs/Data Structures and Algorithms/HW04/WSUStudent.cpp:146:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<WSUStudent*>::insert(std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent>*)’
    s_allStudents.insert(&result);
```

The point of this assignment is to fix memory leaks ('new' statements that don't get deleted with their pointers) by turning normal pointers into weak pointers and shared pointers. The original code is as follows.

```
WSUStudent *WSUStudent::registerStudent(
   std::string lastName,
   std::string firstName
)
{
   auto result = new WSUStudent(lastName, firstName);

   s_allStudents.insert(result);

   return result;
}
```

Am I going about this wrong? I can't get the s_allStudents line to run.

Comment: What type is `s_allStudents`?

Comment: The declaration for s_allStudents is static std::set<WSUStudent *> s_allStudents;   I'm going to try changing the WSUStudent * in the brackets to a shared_ptr while I wait.

Comment: `s_allStudents.insert(&result);` is not good. You are storing a pointer to an object on the stack.

Comment: You could use result.get() to get to the pointer within the shared_ptr object.

Comment: Changing the declaration to use a shared pointer fixed the problem, but created a new one. I will update and answer my own question when I fix the new error. It looks straightforwards.

Comment: Actuallly that result.get() worked perfectly and saved me work. Thank you, please move it to answers so I can select it.

Comment: @user3424549 The solution with `get` is _not_ a good idea.  If you are using `shared_ptr` (which in typical professional applications won't be that often), then _all_ pointers to the object should be `shared_ptr`.  Otherwise, you're just creating future problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the type of `s_allStudents`, you can use:

```
s_allStudents.insert(result.get());
```

However, a better option will be to change type of `s_allStudents`.

```
static std::set<std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent>> s_allStudents;
```

and use:

```
s_allStudents.insert(result);
```

**Update**

The default `operator<()` of `shared_ptr` is such that the objects in `s_allStudents` will be sorted by pointer value. If you would like to sort the objects using a different criterion, you'll need to define a custom functor/function as a parameter of the template.

```
struct MyCompare
{
   bool operator<(shared_ptr<WSUStudent> const& lhs,
                  shared_ptr<WSUStudent> const& rhs) const
   {
      // Implement the logic ...
   }
};
```

and use it as:

```
static std::set<std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent>, MyCompare> s_allStudents;
```

Comment: Don't you mean `std::set<std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent>>`?

Comment: The OP said that the assignment was to return a `std::shared_ptr` from the function. If `s_allStudents` is intended to be the *owner* of the objects (and that looks most likely) then adding the *raw pointer* to one of the owning containers is dangerous. Also if you store the objects by value as in your second example and return a `std::shared_ptr` pointing to those, once again that's UB waiting to happen.

Comment: He might also want to add a comparison operator to the template parameters of `s_allStudents`.  At present, it will order according to memory address.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to return a `std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent>` then you are returning *ownership* rights to the object you created - meaning someone else will be trying to delete it at some point.

Unless you *also* keep *ownership* that means your pointer could get *deleted* before you are finished with it. So you need to also store `std::shared_ptr` in your *static* set:

I am guessing at how you are using this class but what I mean goes something like this:

```
class WSUStudent
{
    // you really need to store shared pointers in here
    static std::set<std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent>> s_allStudents;

    std::string lastName;
    std::string firstName;

    // only the static factory function can make students
    WSUStudent(
        const std::string& lastName, // passing by const& is more usual (idiomatic)
        const std::string& firstName)
    : lastName(lastName)
    , firstName(firstName)
    {
    }

public:

    static std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent> registerStudent(
        const std::string& lastName,
        const std::string& firstName);
};

std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent> WSUStudent::registerStudent(
    const std::string& lastName,
    const std::string& firstName
)
{
    auto result = std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent>(new WSUStudent(lastName, firstName));

    // put the shared student in your set
    s_allStudents.insert(result);

    return result;
}

// define your set
std::set<std::shared_ptr<WSUStudent>> WSUStudent::s_allStudents;

int main ()
{
    // make students
    auto s = WSUStudent::registerStudent("bill", "bob");
    // all deletions should be in order
}
```